# Cifs share on Windows host disconnects, but can still be reached using smblient

Tags: windows, samba, cifs

My small home network includes a Wandboard running Arch Linux ARM and a Windows 7 desktop. The Linux box mounts a cifs share hosted on the Windows 7 machine at boot with no problem. But after a certain amount of time the connection to the Windows share is lost.

I can **cd** to the mount point directory, but when I run **ls** I get the message: `cannot open directory '.': Host is down`. If I unmount the mount directory and try to remount the share, I get a `mount error(2): No such file or directory` error. However, I can connect to the share using **smbclient** with no problem. And if I reboot the Wandboard the share again mounts with no problem. But after a time it becomes inaccessible again.

I've tried several different things on the Windows machine, including enabling and disabling SMB v1 and trying all the possible settings for the NIC (Intel with the latest driver) and for Windows share permissions. But the problem must involve the Linux side, since the share remains available via **smbclient** and mounts with no problem when I reboot. I've updated samba and cifs-utils and tried enabling and disabling winbind. I'm not sure what else to try.

**Further information:**

The mount line I'm using in fstab is: `//192.xxx.x.xx/Work /mnt/Work cifs guest,users,credentials=/home/alarm/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.1 0 0`
But I have tried a number of options, including `noperm` and `_netdev` and using `vers=2.0` and also with no `vers=` option at all.

The command I use to connect via **smbclient** is `sudo smbclient //192.xxx.x.xx/Work -U=alarm` This prompts me for the samba password, which is the same as the password for a user "alarm" on the Windows machine. The username and password are the same as in the credentials file I use to mount the share (and try to re-mount). Once I enter the password I am connected via **smbclient** and can perform read and write operations.

The Windows logs show that **NTLMv2** is being used for authentication when the share is mounted. **smbclient**'s output also shows that **NTLMv2** is being used. However the samba log shows the Linux box trying to use **NTLMv1** to connect, and the user **alarm** (the one I am supposedly connecting to the share as) not being recognized; after that the anonymous user **nobody** seems to be logged on (the Windows host is configured to allow anonymous logon). Might this suggest that the Linux box is trying to use **NTLMv1** to reconnect the share and failing?

Around the time the share disconnects, **dmesg** shows the following: `CIFS VFS: \\192.xxx.x.xx has not responded in 180 seconds. Reconnecting...` - but nothing after that to show there has been a reconnect.

My configuration is as follows:

```
   - Arch Linux ARM version 5.7.2-1-ARCH
     - samba v 4.12.3 
     - cifs-utils v 6.13-2
   - host: Windows 7 Ultimate with SMB1 disabled and SMB2 enabled
```

I will attach a file with more detailed information once I figure out how. But I can provide any information, run tests, etc. as needed - just ask.

Thanks

Les

Comment: I've updated my question as per your suggestions - for which many thanks. Don't hesitate to ask for more info. Please note my remarks on NTLMv1 in "Further information."

Comment: Hello? My question has been updated and is full of information. It's just waiting for someone who has the knowledge and the kindness and the time to respond...

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but it may be a step in the right direction. I now have **strace** and **tshark** outputs from successful and failed **ls** and **mount** commands, as well as for the **smbclient** connection, which always succeeds.

Comparing the **strace** outputs, the key point seems to be (in the successful strace):

```
statx(AT_FDCWD, "/mnt/Work", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT, STATX_MODE, {stx_mask=STATX_TYPE|STATX_MODE|STATX_NLINK|STATX_UID|STATX_GID|STATX_MTIME|STATX_CTIME|STATX_INO|STATX_SIZE|STATX_BLOCKS|STATX_BTIME, stx_attributes=0, stx_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, stx_size=131072, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/mnt/Work", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=131072, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1052672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb68d2000
getdents64(3, 0xb68d2028 /* 65 entries */, 1048576) = 2352
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat64(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=56353, ...}) = 0
read(4, "# GNU libc iconv configuration.\n"..., 4096) = 4096
```

... and then a further series of **read**s (presumably of the files and subdirectories).

The failed connection shows this:

```
statx(AT_FDCWD, "/mnt/Work", AT_STATX_SYNC_AS_STAT, STATX_MODE, 0xbeb86650) = -1 EHOSTDOWN (Host is down)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2998, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2998
```

...and then a **read** and a **write** of the error message (**"Host is down"**).
I can post more of the **strace** output and the **tshark** and **smbclient** outputs too if anyone wishes to see them. TIA